# How to create multiple theme in material angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want apply blue, light blue, green and ornage shade in my appication.I am using material angular theme part.But not getting exactly how to use..i have to create css ?? or js or directive..

Comment: How to create css class for each theme ??

Comment: Can you show us some example? So, we can help you better.

Answer (score 16):

1.) First go through  [theme documentation here](https://material.angularjs.org/#/Theming/01_introduction)

2.) Pick colors from palette ([link](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html))

3.) Create yr own custom theme with colors you want and define it inside app.config.

```
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
          .primaryPalette('blue')
          .accentPalette('indigo')
          .warnPalette('red')
          .backgroundPalette('grey');

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom')
          .primaryPalette('grey')
          .accentPalette('deep-purple')
          .warnPalette('green')

    //create yr own palette 
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('amazingPaletteName', {
        '50': 'ffebee',
        '100': 'ffcdd2',
        '200': 'ef9a9a',
        '300': 'e57373',
        '400': 'ef5350',
        '500': 'f44336',
        '600': 'e53935',
        '700': 'd32f2f',
        '800': 'c62828',
        '900': 'b71c1c',
        'A100': 'ff8a80',
        'A200': 'ff5252',
        'A400': 'ff1744',
        'A700': 'd50000',
        'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',    // whether, by default, text         (contrast)
                                    // on this palette should be dark or light
        'contrastDarkColors': ['50', '100', //hues which contrast should be 'dark' by default
         '200', '300', '400', 'A100'],
        'contrastLightColors': undefined    // could also specify this if default was 'dark'
    });

   $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom2')
        .primaryPalette('amazingPaletteName')

}
```

4.) Then on yr html u can just use these theme

```
<div>
   <md-button class="md-primary">I will be blue (by default)</md-button>
   <div md-theme="custom">
      <md-button class="md-primary">I will be grey(custom)</md-button>
   </div>
   <div md-theme="custom2">
      <md-button class="md-primary">I will be red(custom2)</md-button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added same code but still background color of pallete has not chnaged.. :(

Comment: there was some issue with background (https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1450), its fixed in latest version. Try updating yr angular-material.

Comment: i want to use white color as primary one, how can i?

Comment: You should follow step 3 from answer and use different shades of white while defining your palette.