# angular material: using palette colours

Tags: angular-material

It's possible to configure or choose your own colour palette with `$mdThemingProvider` as it's shown [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme), but how can I actually use these colours? Say, how do I create a `div` filled with the `50`'s shade of `backgroundPalette`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30162974/3322160